# Magento2 installation stuck on user configuration (49%) on Ubuntu vagrant

Tags: magento2, installation

I try to install **Magento2** on my **Ubuntu** using **vagrant**,

the installation stuck on

> " Installing user configuration... "

without any error.

[image]

Comment: It cab be an execution time issue please increase the max_execution_time in your php.ini file

Comment: @ABHISHEKTRIPATHI still not work sir

Comment: you are working on a local instance or a live server?

Comment: @ABHISHEKTRIPATHI I work on VM using Vagrant

Comment: The VM it's on my local computer (not remote)

Comment: stop installation and retry

Comment: @magefms I try, but always stuck on user configuration

Comment: I see, you should modify your max_execution_time setting change its value to 18000. It should do the trick

Comment: I do it, sir, when I try the install it the first time I get this error `configuration for DB connection is absent`

Comment: btw, which magento2 version you are using?

Comment: @magefms Magento 2.3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91404/discussion-between-magefms-and-sayou).

Comment: I think the problem is on the Vagrant-Ubuntu configuration and exactly when I use NFS sharing folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after increasing `max_execution_time` `max_input_time` and `memory_limit` to the recommended values, and disabling xdebug (or at least increasing xdebug.max_nesting_level) [doc here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/trouble/tshoot_install-issues.html), the installation was still stuck,

then I tried updating my env.php file with this cache section :

```
'cache' => [
    'frontend' => [
        'default' => [
            'backend' => 'Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis',
            'backend_options' => [
                'server' => '127.0.0.1',
                'database' => '0',
                'port' => '6379'
            ],
            'id_prefix' => 'f19_'
        ],
        'page_cache' => [
            'backend' => 'Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis',
            'backend_options' => [
                'server' => '127.0.0.1',
                'port' => '6379',
                'database' => '1',
                'compress_data' => '0'
            ],
            'id_prefix' => 'f19_'
        ]
    ]
],
```

I'm still trying to know why it worked ! Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I didn't do anything more than adding this line in my .htaccess

```
php_value  xdebug.max_nesting_level 500
```

It worked for me